# Invalid Characters causing error in rlm()

Tags: r, invalid-characters

A data frame which has invalid characters in the column names is causing an error in rlm().

Taking a deeper look, it appears that within rlm() the variable `xvars` contains the names of the formula's explanatory variables, but it puts backticks around the offending names.  Then when xvars is used as an index to a data frame, namesly `mf[xvars]` it causes the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, xvars) : undefined columns selected
```

Is this the expected behavior? (I realize the keyword phrase *invalid* characters).
Curiously, calling lm() on the same model and dataframe causes no problems.

```
# SAMPLE DATA
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(36),ncol=6))
colnames(mydf) <- c("y", "x1", "x2", "x1^2", "x2^2", "x1:x2")

rlm(y~., data=mydf)  # Error

lm(y~., data=mydf)   # No Problem

# Clean up column names
colnames(mydf) <- make.names(colnames(mydf))
rlm(y~., data=mydf) # No Problem
```

Taking a look at `MASS:::rlm.formula`, it appears the error is 
caused by `mf[xvars]` in the following lines:

```
xlev <- if (length(xvars) > 0L) {
    xlev <- lapply(mf[xvars], levels)
    xlev[!sapply(xlev, is.null)]
}
```

Any thoughts why the backticks are being added but then causing an error?

---

Additional Info

I copied the rlm() function, added `dput(mf)` & `dput(xvars)` and got the following values. *Note that the value of xvars is different than the names assigned above (ie, backticks are added). Also, the names of mf are the same as the names given above.*

```
# dput yielded
mf <- structure(list(y = c(-0.242914027018629, 0.724255425682537, -0.0578467214604185, -0.274193999595702, -0.38985000750839, 0.406046200943395), x1 = c(1.53071709960635, -1.87493297716611, 1.0936519723035, -0.977011182431237, -0.510890461021046, 1.20136627562427), x2 = c(-0.801995963036553, 1.30590232081605, 0.635922235436178, -1.86824341731708, -2.76797814532917, -0.497992681627495), `x1^2` = c(0.914146279518207, 0.103458073891876, -1.29818230391818, -0.629048606358592, 1.71534374557621, 0.922690967521984), `x2^2` = c(-0.0879726513660469, 1.05299413769867, 1.01955640371072, 0.546413685721721, 0.947757793667223, -0.0998700630220064), `x1:x2` = c(-0.757490494166813, 1.31307393014016, 1.90233916482184, 0.68844011701049, -1.28717997826724, -0.581800325341162)), .Names = c("y", "x1", "x2", "x1^2", "x2^2", "x1:x2"), terms = y ~     x1 + x2 + `x1^2` + `x2^2` + `x1:x2`, row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
xvars <- c("x1", "x2", "`x1^2`", "`x2^2`", "`x1:x2`")

mf[xvars]  
# Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, xvars) : undefined columns selected


# Removing the backticks from xvars eliminates the error.
xvars <- sapply(xvars, function(x) gsub("`", "", x))
mf[xvars2]  # No Error
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question - you're asking why an R function has a bug in it?

Comment: @hadley Sorry for the lack of clarity. The title of the question is misleading as I originally encountered this running lm() and then trying to run rlm().    The question should really be why are backticks being added, but then causing an error.  I'll clean this up a bit

Comment: The obvious answer is to not use characters in list names that are also formula operators.  While I can't say for sure, I would suspect that this is what is confusing rlm.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg.  You're certainly right, and that is what I ended up doing. However, I am still curious why this is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue boils down to the fact you are using non-syntatic variable names.

These should be used with caution, and without expectation that package authors will be able to anticipate any issues that may arise.

To quote from the help for `formula`

> Variable names can be quoted by backticks `like this` in formulae,
>   although there is no guarantee that all code using formulae will
>   accept such non-syntactic names.

The issue  in how `xvars` is created `rlm.formula`

```
xvars <- as.character(attr(mt, "variables"))[-1L]
```

and then the use later on

```
xlev <- if (length(xvars) > 0L) {
        xlev <- lapply(mf[xvars], levels)
        xlev[!sapply(xlev, is.null)]
    }
```

Which, as you show, does not work

This will create quoted back-ticked variables for non-syntatic names. If they are already backticked, then  they will create double back-ticked names

i.e. if the column name was `"x1^2"`, the element in `xvar` becomes `` "`x1^2`" ``.

This fails with `[.data.frame` for example

```
x <- data.frame(`a` = 1)
> x[,'`a`']

Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , "`a`") : undefined columns selected
```

Because the column name is `'a'` not `` `a` ``

If you backtick the column name

i.e. if the column name was `` "`x1^2`" ``, the element in `xvar` becomes ``` "``x1^2``" ```.

which again is not a column in your data.frame

The reason `lm` works is that it does not attempt this definition and use of `xvars`, instead it uses `model.matrix` to define the design matrix `x` directly to pass to `lm.fit`

If you want to fit the model `y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 +x1^2 + y1^2` then you can using

```
rlm(y ~ x1*x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2)
```

In this case you only need three columns in your data.frame (or objects in your evaluation environment) `y`, `x1` and `x2`. as the `I()` function allows to perform arithmetic operations on a variable, as `I` is parsed as a symbol by  `terms.formula`

Comment: What do you mean about `I()` resulting in the names? You could avoid the issue forcing syntatic names using `colnames(mydf) <- make.names(c("y", "x1", "x2", "x1^2", "x2^2", "x1:x2"))`