# R rlm is giving errors

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have this code with `lm()` function:

```
lm.monto <- lm(`201901` ~ `201902`+`201903`+`201904`+`201905`+`201906`+`201907`+`201908`+`201909`,data = cashback_monto)
```

It works properly, but once i try to use `rlm()` to make a robust model, it doesnt work:

```
rlm(`201901` ~ `201902`+`201903`+`201904`+`201905`+`201906`+`201907`+`201908`+`201909`,data = cashback_monto)
```

Im getting this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, xvars) : undefined columns selected
```

My data is 10 columns (one per year) with values higher than zero. It looks like this, but with ~60k observations:

[image]

Comment: Please make your example reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Perhaps the link below might provide an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327287/invalid-characters-causing-error-in-rlm

Answer (score 0):

What return do you get with `colnames(cashback_monto)` ?